# ember-cli-pagination Remote Paginated API doesn't work with latest ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, pagination, ember-cli

Every time I try to use it (https://github.com/mharris717/ember-cli-pagination), I get this error:

```
File: fit2me-admin/routes/users.js
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/johndoe/fit2me-admin/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-StzgqLlh.tmp/ember-cli-pagination/addon/remote/route-mixin.js'
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/johndoe/fit2me-admin/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-StzgqLlh.tmp/ember-cli-pagination/addon/remote/route-mixin.js'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:696:18)
    at addModule (/Users/johndoe/fit2me-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/index.js:84:46)
    at addModule (/Users/johndoe/fit2me-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/index.js:133:9)
    at /Users/johndoe/fit2me-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/index.js:59:7
    at $$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/johndoe/fit2me-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:470:16)
    at $$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/johndoe/fit2me-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:482:17)
    at $$$internal$$publish (/Users/johndoe/fit2me-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:453:11)
    at $$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/johndoe/fit2me-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1531:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

Before this error though I get similar error, but that's because it tries to look for `remote/` folder without going into `addon/` folder first.

And yes, I already tried:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm -rf bower_components/
npm cache clean
bower cache clean
npm install
bower install
```

and it didn't work :(